# Android Custom ListView IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, listview, filter, refresh, indexoutofboundsexception

I need your help.

I have a custom list view with three elements. When I press the plus button, a new item will be added to the list. And the `ListView` should be updated.

But I get the following error

```
    04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601): Process: de.schatner.sino.main, PID: 32601
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 8, size is 8
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at de.schatner.sino.main.MainActivity$ListAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:201)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2823)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1884)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:713)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:677)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:7040)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:4162)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.widget.AbsListView.startScrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:4090)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:5511)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:5366)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8981)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2410)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:5308)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2568)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1776)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2866)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2529)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9186)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4706)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4544)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4201)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4095)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4095)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6564)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6454)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6425)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6654)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6625)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6677)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
04-16 15:54:52.177: E/AndroidRuntime(32601):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Chor
```

I am posting my code below:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayList<NoticeDTO> lists = null;
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;
    final Activity activity = this;
    public int i=1;
    private EditText et_search;
    private SQLiteHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ActionBar bar = this.getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#48cfae")));
        bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        Window window = getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.flattygreendark));

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbHandler = new SQLiteHandler(this);
        LinkedList<NoticeDTO> notices= dbHandler.getAllNotes();
        lists = new ArrayList<NoticeDTO>();
        lists.addAll(notices);
        this.listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, lists);
        setListAdapter(this.listAdapter);
        this.getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        this.et_search=  (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.et_search);
        this.et_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                MainActivity.this.listAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        final Button bt_delete= (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.bt_delete);
        bt_delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_search.setText("");
            }
        });

        final Button bt_set_event= (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.bt_new_event);
        bt_set_event.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

                String date=""+calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"."+calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"."+calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                date+=" "+sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

                try{
                    long rowId= dbHandler.insertNewNotice("Testliste für den zzz Einkauf \n"
                            + "laoasd asdj asdjas ",date,date);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                LinkedList<NoticeDTO> notices = new LinkedList<NoticeDTO>();
                notices= dbHandler.getAllNotes();
                lists.clear();
                lists.addAll(notices);
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        NoticeDTO notice=(NoticeDTO) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoticeActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("text", notice.getText());
        i.putExtra("noticeId", notice.getId());
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        this.onCreate(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //private class
    private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NoticeDTO> {

        private ArrayList<NoticeDTO> originalList;
        private ArrayList<NoticeDTO> noticeList;
        private NoticeFilter filter;

        public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<NoticeDTO> noticeList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, noticeList);

            this.noticeList = new ArrayList<NoticeDTO>();
            this.noticeList.addAll(noticeList);
            this.originalList = new ArrayList<NoticeDTO>();
            this.originalList.addAll(noticeList);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            if (filter == null) {
                filter = new NoticeFilter();
            }
            return filter;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView toptext;
            TextView bottomtext;
            TextView footertext;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v= convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.toptext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                holder.bottomtext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
                holder.footertext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.footertext);
                v.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }

            NoticeDTO notice = noticeList.get(position);
            if (notice != null) {
                if(notice.getText().length()>20){
                    holder.toptext.setText(notice.getText().substring(0, 20)+"...");
                }else{
                    holder.toptext.setText(notice.getText());
                }
                holder.bottomtext.setText(notice.getCreate_date()+"(ID: "+notice.getId()+")");
                holder.footertext.setText("Zuletzt geändert am: "+notice.getEdit_date());
            }
            return v;
        }

        private class NoticeFilter extends Filter{

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.GERMANY);
                FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0){
                    ArrayList<NoticeDTO> filteredItems = new ArrayList<NoticeDTO>();
                    for(int i = 0, l = originalList.size(); i < l; i++){
                        NoticeDTO notice = originalList.get(i);
                         if(notice.getText().toLowerCase(Locale.GERMANY).contains(constraint)){
                             filteredItems.add(notice);
                         }
                    }
                    result.count = filteredItems.size();
                    result.values = filteredItems;
                }else{
                     synchronized(this){
                     result.values = originalList;
                     result.count = originalList.size();
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                noticeList = (ArrayList<NoticeDTO>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                clear();
                for(int i = 0, l = noticeList.size(); i < l; i++){
                    add(noticeList.get(i));
                }
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The refresh of the `ListView` does not work.

Help somebody please!

Comment: Check the null pointer exception and list size before performing operations of list. So that you can avoid these type of ecxeptions

Comment: at which line its throwing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is an IndexOutOfBoundsException occuring at line 201 of your code (getView method of your ListAdapter private class) In the future please add a comment at the line that is causing the exception.
Upon further analysis, the line of code throwing the exception is:

```
NoticeDTO notice = noticeList.get(position);
```

Two things. First, you can fix the exception by saying:

```
NoticeDTO notice = noticeList.get(position-1);
```

The reason for position -1 is that you are trying to use "int position" input parameter of getView. This position variable is not zero-indexed like an array. In other words, you tried to get the list item at position 8; however your arrayList size is 8 (indexes from 0 to 7)

Second, this code is outside of any if-else logic. Later on, if you decide to add deleting functionality (removing items from your list) youll save yourself some headache if you check to see if the list is empty before you try use position.